# Implementing beforeedit listener on a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to implement the **beforeedit** listener in my table. I would like to do some checking before a user is allowed to do something to the cell.

```
    Ext.define('myGrid', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        listeners: {
          beforeedit: function (e) {
            alert('hi')
          },
        }
```

When I try and edit a cell, this **alert(..)** is not called. Why is this not going into the listener? If I look on the internet there are plenty of examples of Ext.grid.Panel with beforeedit.

Anyway I tried to extend with **Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel** instead.

```
    Ext.define('myGrid', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel',

        listeners: {
          beforeedit: function (e) {
            alert('hi')
          }
        }
```

Now I get an obscure error in typical extjs fashion :

http://jsfiddle.net/S8Tgm/13/

What am I doing wrong? And why should you use EditorGridPanel over normal grid? Is it for the Excel like properties?

**EDIT** : yes. sorry i forgot to put beforeedit in 'listeners'. Question still stands as is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function (e) {
        alert('hi')
    }
},
plugins: [
  Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', { //or even better - use ptype here
     clicksToEdit: 1
})],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8Tgm/12/ - working fiddle

You miss a few things:

Grid has NO 'beforeedit' event. You need to add an editor to your grid  [Example is here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/docs/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.1/viewer.html)

Events should be put in the "listeners" object

(having big troubles with stackoverflow markup)

Comment: is there any way of doing this without the RowEditing plugin?

Comment: I'm kinda missing the point here.. You can use CellEditor instead. Do you need an event to fire when the checkbox is clicked? without actual row editing? Here's sencha docs on grid:  [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) - check "Events" dropdown to see all the events usable with grid (without any plugins)

Comment: Yep. You can not edit grid records inline without having one ;)

Comment: @РоманГуйван how can you accomplish that?